# Should we force users to have an actual question in their question?

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that a lot of bad questions aren't even questions (have no actual question in them). They usually go something like:

> I'm trying to do X. It should do A, B and C.

I realize that these "questions" can easily be be translated into

> How do I do X? It should do A, B and C.

**Is this something we should try to prevent? If so, what can we do?**

The most simple thing would be to inform the poster of a question that their question doesn't include a question mark. I *may* cause them to rethink their question before even posting it. The presence of a questions mark could either be enforced (i.e. you can't post a question without it) or just encouraged (i.e. the questioner get informed about the missing question mark but can still post the question).

I could also see the possibility of a more advanced heuristic that tries to inform users that it looks like they are posting a question that probably is not a good fit for the community.

Comment: Or you can simply (suggest an) edit if you get the question.

Comment: The existence (or lack thereof) of a `?` is rather meaningless. Bad questions will be bad with or without enforcing this.

Comment: I consider the difference between "I'm trying to..." and "How do I..." to be very minor. What is important is how clear and specific are X, A, B, and C.

Comment: If you force the existence of a question mark people will just add one to the end of a statement, which isn't helpful, just confusing?

Comment: Related: [How can we get more people to make their title a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21606), [Requiring a question mark in the question body for new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169643), [What about checking for a question mark in the post title on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118150)

Answer (score 5):

I don't care how it's phrased, as long as it's perfectly clear what the problem is.

If the author's communication skills are sufficient so that the question is understandable even without a question mark, so be it. If not, suggest an edit (or edit, if you have the privilege) and make it clearer.